# How to use an ARRAYFORMULA to create a list of game mod dependents, given a list of mod ids and dependencies

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Sorry if the title is confusing but [here is a example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fa5hkYxzLMvObrZi3l9fzpzjSaLWDFUwtYuc9E05OK0/edit?usp=sharing)

that will hopefully make some sense. I have a list of game mods which each have a Mod ID and a list of dependencies (which is basically a comma separated list of other mod IDs). I've filled in the "Dependents" (yellow) column with the data I'd expect to see but I'd like that to be accomplished by using an ARRAYFORMULA.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,textjoin(", ",1,index(if(regexmatch(B:B,"\b"&Σ&"\b"),A:A,))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wait, there's an issue. If one Mod ID is simply "MrBob", it will register for all ones that depend on "MrBobsLib" too. I guess the search is not looking for a whole word?

Comment: Do try out the updated answer.